# Java Inheritance - cannot find Symbol Constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

I can't figure out how to compile my subclass even though it calls the superclasses constructor?

This is the class that won't compile:

```
package departments;
import employees.*;

public class DepartmentEmployee extends Employee{

    private Department department;

    public DepartmentEmployee(Profile profile, Address address, Occupation occupation,   Department department) {
        assert (department != null) : "invalid Department";
        super(profile, address, occupation);
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

This is the superclass:

```
package employees;

public class Employee {

    protected Profile profile;
    protected Address address;
    protected Occupation occupation;

    protected Employee(Profile profile, Address address, Occupation occupation) {
        assert (profile != null) : "invalid Profile";
        assert (address != null) : "invalid Address";
        assert (occupation != null) : "invalid Occupation";
        this.profile = profile;
        this.address = address;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

}
```

The subclass keeps on saying "cannot find symbol - constructor Employee". The two are in different packages. Did I link them correctly?

Comment: In your DepartmentEmployee, shouldn't super(...) be the first call in the ctor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `super()` needs to be the **first** call in the constructor. Rearrange it above the `assert`.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorial - Using the keyword `super`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) (extract below)

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor.